# Is the use of "this" correct in "There is this blog, but I don't remember its name"?

Tags: word-usage, determiners

What I write should mean the following: "There is this blog, but I don't remember its name."

So I thought I have to write it this way to achieve the meaning in a short way: "This blog."

But is this correct? Does is mean what I want to say? Because I've learned at school that "this" points to something specific. But I that's not what I want to achieve.

Sorry if the question is unclear. But I have no idea how to explain it differently.

Comment: *its name* not *his name*.

Comment: Yes, thx. It should be correct now.

Comment: Using *this* this way is fine both in German and English. Using commas before coordinating *that* and *what* is only fine in German, but not in English. Using "I've" to contract the main verb in the sentence is only fine in British English, but is ungrammatical in American English.

Comment: I'd have said, *"There is this here blog"* . . . :)

Answer (score 4):

The term 'this' is often used by people to refer to something specific but unidentified.

'I was driving along Princess Parkway, when this green car shot out in front of me'.

Some might argue that it is grammatically incorrect as 'this' is normally only used to refer to something nearby at the time of speaking, or where let's say a photograph of the object is presented to the listener. Strictly speaking they are correct. But the form quoted has become almost an accepted idiom.

However speaking personally, I would say '...when a green car shot out in front of me'.

Comment: True...except when you want to refer to the same green car later..."and then a few miles up the road, I saw it pulled over by a cop car! Justice!"

Comment: -1 the car has been identified ("green car shot out in front of me"); what *this* does not do is make a definite reference. Thus, the *this* under discussion has been called the *indefinite this* (Google it, if you like). A definite reference and a specific reference are two different *grammatical* categories.

Comment: @user1284969632635 I've no doubt it can be given a name. And I've no objection to people using it. And it can form part of literature, since that is the way people speak. But use it in a university essay in Britain, other than as a quotation, or fictional representation and it will attract red ink.  "There was this character Guy Fawkes, who tried to blow up Parliament" will not persuade the professorial class that you are a fully literate person.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written

> There is this blog, but I don't remember its name.

seems fine as you are referring to one specific blog.

You could also use

> There is a blog, but I don't remember its name.

but 'this' is the definite article, and you are talking about just one blog, so your sentence is perfect.

Comment: -1 *this* is not the definite article